# Documenting many to many relationship with Swagger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm building a Rails app that is API only, and documenting the API using [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/)
It works very well, but I'm not able to understand how to add a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

```
class Location
  has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers
end

class Supplier
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

Now, I see other 'singular' relationshops represented inside a "relationships" hash with type "object" and "properties" set as links.

A person has one ethnicity:

```
"relationships": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ethnicity": {
      "$ref": "ethnicity_reference.json#/EthnicityReference",
      "description": "Person's ethnicity"
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't apparently figure out how to represent many to many relationships, and so far failed to find any example.
Does anybody have any pointer or suggestion?